# How can I get the NDK version during compile time?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I've searched and it seems that at some point `__NDK_MAJOR__` was at least proposed but at least as of NDK 15c it doesn't seem to be set.

Is there a way within the preprocessor to determine the NDK version being used to build from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in r16. If you need to know the version before then, you'll need to parse the `$NDK/source.properties` file and pass it as a define to your code as part of your build system.

Comment: So it's true, by `#include <android/ndk-version.h>` you can check `__NDK_MAJOR__`, unfortunately that header didn't exist before NDK 16 so I am still stuck with a backwards compatible way to check for the NDK version. At least going forward we have something. If anyone sees a backwards compat solution please comment.

Comment: iirc that header is included by android/api-level.h. If not, wrap the include in `#if __has_include <android/ndk-version.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

try these:

```
#include <android/api-level.h>
#ifdef __ANDROID_API_O_MR1__
#    include <android/ndk-version.h>
#    ifdef __NDK_MAJOR__
#        define MY_NDK_VERSION   __NDK_MAJOR__
#    else
#        define MY_NDK_VERSION   16
#    endif
#else
#    define MY_NDK_VERSION       14
#endif
```